# Connect to a SQL Server using IP address?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a database on SQL Server using IP address (SQL Server is on another PC), but I am facing issues in connecting to the database.

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
        "Server=192.168.1.12;"
        "port=1433;"
        "Network Library=DBMSSOCN;"
        "Database=tpms;"
        "Trusted_Connection=no;"
        "uid=malhar;"
        "pwd=malhar1234;")

try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect(cnxn)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    create_table = '''
        CREATE TABLE tpms_info (
            tyre_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
            tyre_position VARCHAR(50)
        )
    '''

    cursor.execute(create_table)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

Here, I am writing a simple code to create a new table inside of `tpms` database.

I have created a new user and trying to connect it using those credentials. The credentials are correct as the server locally. I have also SQL Server Configuration Manager, I have enabled TCP/IP under protocols tab.
The method works when I am trying to connect to a local server but fails to connect to remote servers.
When, `cnxn` is as follows:

```
cnxn = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
        "Server=DESKTOP-PTGDG1D\SQLEXPRESS;"
        "Database=ateq;"
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

The table is created inside of the database, but this connection is local. Are there any steps I am missing out?
I have also created a new inbound rule in firewall to allow incoming request on port 1433.

Here is the error message:

> Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)')

Comment: Add the error message to your question. Is the remote server also a named instance?

Comment: Double check "ServerProperties | Connections | Remote server connections" and make sure that "Allow remote connections to this server" is set correctly.

Comment: @RossBush "Allow remote connections to this server" is enabled as well as server authentication is set to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you elaborate on the instance name please?

Comment: Connecting using the IP address is no different to using the hostname. If your connection via IP is failing, then it would fail with the host name as well. The problem being the "IP" is almost certainly irrelevant.

Comment: Do you have enabled [remote connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver16) via ip on your sql Server Installation?

Comment: @Malhar, when you view the SQL Server Services with SQL Server Configuration Manager, the instance name is displayed in parenthesis. SQL Server Express edition is usually installed as a name instance so it will show as "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)". The default instance will usually show (MSSQLSERVER). The default instance usually listens on port 1433 and named instances on a different port.

Comment: @Hermann12 Yes, remote connection via ip is enabled.

Comment: @DanGuzman The instance name here is SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: @Malhar, it seems the instance is not listening on the 1433 port specified in yourconnection string. If you don't have other SQL instances on the machine, change the port to 1433 and restart the service.

Comment: What I have done now: Under sql server configuration manager -> SQL Server network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS-> TCP/IP -> IPAll Addresses: TCP Dynamic port is set to 51434 and TCP Port is 1433.

Comment: Seems to be multiple issues in play here: 1) protocol, and 2) networking. 1) The error message indicates that it's trying to use Named Pipes protocol which requires multiple ports to be open on firewalls and the target computer (think: File and Printer Sharing). Try adding `Network=dbmssocn;` to your connection string to use the TCP/IP protocol instead. 2) How remote are the "remote servers?" The first connection string works with `192.168.1.12` which is a private IP address, likely on the `192.168.1.0/24` network. It should work for computers on that network - but not over the internet.

Comment: Note that @AlwaysLearning suggested `Network=dbmssocn;`, not `Network Library=…` as you tried earlier. You might also try `Server=tcp:192.168.1.12;`

Comment: Depends on the driver and version, but `Net`, `Network` and `Network Library` are often synonyms for one another.

Comment: Also note that the second connection string is trying to use an Instance Name, `\SQLEXPRESS`, which requires that the udp/1434 port is also open and accessible to pass through SSRP requests to the SQL Browser service. If you know the port of the instance in advance then use it in the `Server` property with a comma separator, i.e.: for an instance listening on port 2345 you'd use `Server=serverNameOrIpAddress,2345;`. You shouldn't need either the instance name or the port number for instances configured to listen on the default 1433 port.

Comment: Also worth noting that the error message is coming from "Named Pipes Provider" because that is the last provider in the default Windows client setup ProtocolOrder. It tries Shared Memory (sm), then TCP/IP (tcp), and then Named Pipes (np). ref: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI18.0\ProtocolOrder`

Comment: Might be worth it to try connecting to the remote SQL server using different software, such as SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio just to verify that you can connect.  I find it easier to troubleshoot using a client where I can quickly change settings and test again.